# Mercurial different heads

Tags: mercurial

we are a team of 3 developers using Mercurial as a SCM tool, and I recently noticed the current heads (revision numbers) are different between the 3 of us, after everybody has pulled the latest changeset from the central repository. I'm at 2483 and the others are at 2482 (numbers are arbitrary, but mine is +1 compared to the others'). Is this something normal? Because it looks to me as a problem.

We've recently worked on a branch, then switched back to the default branch and merged with the branch. The only thing I can think of is that 2 of us did the merge and pushed the merge to the central repository, instead of only one doing the merge, pushing, and the others pulling the merge. Can someone help with an idea, maybe this is normal after all?

Answer (score 4):

Things to look at:

`12455:8b908304cb1c` is the revision number of my current head. `12455` is a local number, it's only valid for my local repository, it's not global identifier portable between my own repos, or between my repos and my coworkers. `8b908304cb1c` on the other hand is a globally usable identifier. `8b908304cb1c` locally can be used to refer to the exactly same revision in every repository that contains that commit

`hg outgoing` will show you what needs to be pushed. `hg incoming` will show you what you've forgotten to pull.

`hg heads --topo` will show you the topological, unclosed, heads. This will quickly show you if you've got unmerged changes in a branch, or multiple heads in a single branch.

Comment: Everything seems to be in sync, no incoming, no outgoing ... So am I correct to assume that the first number (12455) can be different between developers machines, but the second one should always be the same if local repositories are in sync?

Comment: The hash will be identical, the number might not, and is documented to be a shorthand *locally* to refer to change sets, but not globally usable. So yes, what you're seeing is correct and does not indicate a problem.